# Implementing oAuth login w/ Facebook - getting 'isCancelled' when user declines email permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth-2.0, authorization, fbsdk

I am working on the frontend implementation of facebook authentication for an app using `FBSDK 4.0`.  I'm specifically using `FBSDKLoginManager` to handle the login dialog flow.  On tapping a custom `continue with facebook` button, I trigger the oAuth flow.  The app then pushes to a native Facebook app, or a safari view controller and requests authorization with email permission.  When they just agree, the completion handler: `handler` is invoked with the error and `result` and I will have no error and `results.isCancelled` is `NO`.

However, if I go through the dialog flow again but decline the email permission, the completion handler is invoked with `result.isCancelled` as `YES`.  Therefore, I never enter the else block to send the access token to the backend.

But I'm now confused because as I see things declining the email permission is not `cancelling`.  In fact there is a completely separate 'cancel' option in the facebook safari flow that I'm not tapping.  I need to send the access token to back end in both cases, so even if the email is not present.  I could just get rid of the `result.isCancelled` conditional but it turns out that `result.token` is nil.  I seem to be able to get a token through `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString` but I'm not sure if that is still valid given the login seems to have failed.

What am I missing here?

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"email"]
                 fromViewController:self
                            handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Process error");
                                } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                    // result is cancelled simply by declining email permissions.
                                    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                                } else {
                                 // pass access token to back end to synchronize with our own user account
                                }
}];
```

Comment: You are asking for read permissions for email.  If the user declines that permission then they have cancelled. The behaviour you are seeing looks correct to me

Comment: They are still authorizing.  There is a button to cancel.  The situation I'm describing is when they simply uncheck the email permission.  I'm stilling getting the user id and they're still signaling there desire to authorize the app.  I could, for instance, authenticate them based on the access token, n o?  So i don't get how this is "cancelled".  its only a sub part of the authorization that is cancelled.